# "Путеводная звезда" українською

Tags: переклад, from-russian

В онлайн-перекладачі "путеводная" - дороговказ. Як тоді перекласти "путеводная звезда"? Доровказна зірка?

На http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/7/53407/100986.html знайшла такий варіант:

> ПУТЕВОДНАЯ ЗВЕЗДА - провідна зоря (зірка)

Який переклад правильний? До чого тут дороговказ?

Comment: «Чи варто?» — це суто opinion-based запитання, VTC.

Comment: [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) підтримує *провідну зорю*

Comment: мене збентежив переклад самого слова "путеводная" (дороговказ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Є одне просте правило:

**Не зважайте на онлайн-перекладачі.** Там дуже багато помилок, багато перекладів роблять машини, багато перекладів - волонтери, це не професійний ресурс, максимум - помічний, коли всі решта словників не дають відповіді на питання. Звернемося до перевірених часом словників:

[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=37916&page=1186):

> **Провідна зоря (зірка)** - хтось або щось, що визначає напрям у житті,
>   скеровує чиюсь діяльність. Багато дала ти [музо] мені підмоги на сьому
>   широкому світі – В моїм непривітнім житті ти була провідною зорею
>   (Панас Мирний); Я розкривав перед дітьми яскраві образи людей, імена
>   яких стали для багатьох поколінь провідною зіркою (В. Сухомлинський);
>   Все своє творче життя Марія Костянтинівна [Заньковецька] була зразком
>   і провідною зорею для молодого покоління акторів (з мемуарної літ.);

[Кримський, Єфремов](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on):

> -зда́ путеводная – **провідна́ зоря́ (зі́рка, зірни́ця)**.

[Ізюмов](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=2&highlight=on):

> Звезда – зоря́, -рі́, зі́рка, -ки, зірни́ця, -і; путеводная з. –
>   **провідна́ зоря́, зі́рка**.

[Вирган, Пилипинська](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=7&highlight=on):

> Путеводная звезда (перен.) – **провідна зірка (зоря)**.

Відповідь: так, можна використовувати саме цей вираз як відповідник.

Answer (score 2):

Згідний із відповідю доданою раніше, що найкращим варіантом буде ["провідна зоря (зірка)"](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/7/53407/100986.html).

Однак, знайшов ще такий варіант як "[**дороговказ**](http://ru.howtosay.org/ru_uk/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0)", наприклад:

> Добродетель – наша защита и путеводная звезда, которая хранит наше
>   благоразумие даже тогда, когда наши чувства ошибаются.

Переклад:

> Доброчесність — наш захист і дороговказ, що пробуджує судження, коли
>   почуття хиблять.

Або навіть слово "**маяк**":

> Каждая сестра, если она живет как женщина, преданная Богу, становится
>   путеводной звездой, за которой будут следовать, и сажает семена
>   праведного влияния, урожай от которых будут пожинать еще десятки лет.

Переклад:

> Кожна сестра, яка живе як жінка Бога, стає маяком для інших, щоб
>   показувати дорогу і сіяти зерна праведного впливу, врожай яких буде
>   зібрано десятиліттями пізніше.

Або "**дороговказна зірка**":

> Это наша “путеводная звезда; это якорь нашей души”.

Перклад:

> Воно є “дороговказною зіркою,... якорем для наших душ”.

Також, може бути переклад "**Полярна зірка**", адже вона часто використовується для пошуку напрямку.